# CSS Flexbox - How to make child elements use the remaining vertical space

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex layout like below :

[image: current layout]

And as I described in the title, I'm trying to achieve this kind of result:

[image: desired result]

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRqBLL)

I've tried setting `flex-direction` to `column` but it doesn't work.

```
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```